# Facebook 360 Photo sphere sharing

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp-3.0, sharing, photosphere

We have used an [LG 360 Cam](http://www.lg.com/us/mobile-accessories/lg-LGR105.AVRZTS-360-cam) to take a Facebook Photosphere. This photosphere is currently located on our website and we want to share it on a user's Facebook wall or timeline.

Can we share a Photosphere from an external source (as mentioned above - our site), like a link, and view it on Facebook without uploading it to Facebook servers via [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk)?